# SVN:List all checked in files

Tags: svn

I want to know if there is any sort of query which can list all the files that are checked in   to SVN by a certain user?

Regards,
Pavan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like this help you?

```
svn list -v http://svn.repo/path/to/dir | grep username
```

Comment: I think you need -v on a svn list to get the usernames included. This would be the name of the user who made the most recent commit to the file.

Comment: Thanks.That worked like a charm.In case if you want to search through child directories,add -R to the command - svn list -vR http://svn.repo/path/to/dir | grep username

Comment: --recursive or --depth=infinity or -R for recursive directory listing

Answer (score 1):

You could do `svn log URL --xml -v` and then parse the XML for commits by the user you are interested in. The action attribute on each path would tell you whether it was an "A" addition of a new file or a "M" modification of an existing file.